# Angular/Karma: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'module' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, angular-mock

So I'm trying to use the Karma test runner on my Angular project, but I keep getting this error:

> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app.auth' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I have all my `.js` files in a scripts folder, that my `karma.conf.js` is pointing to, but for some reason I keep getting that error.

My `karma.conf.js` file looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '.',
    frameworks: ['mocha'],
    files: [
      '../bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      '../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      '../scripts/app.module.js',
      '../scripts/**/*.js',
      './unit/*.js'
    ],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this issue?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Could you please provide the spec that you are trying to run. Generally this error occurs when respective module is not loaded in the spec.

Try loading the angular module in a beforeEach block

```
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app.auth'));
```